# Is there any way to implement socket.io with flutter?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, flutter, real-time, flutter-dependencies

I have a back end which contains socket.io for the purpose of real time communication. Also I do know that flutter has a concept of web sockets. But how do I connect the flutter web sockets to my socket.io connection? Is it possible to do using native flutter web sockets? Or is there any package available in pubspec for that?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I try to do the same and I do not find any answer

Comment: @fvisticot Not yet. Some suggested to implement socket.io plugin in native android and then use intents to connect to flutter. I don't know how to do it though